# mod_rest installation on ejabberd 16.06 windows

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erlang-otp, ejabberd-module

I have installed ejabberd 16.06 version on windows. Installation was successful and I need to install mod_rest module.

I followed following steps to install the module and also available modules:

```
    C:\Program Files\ejabberd-16.06\bin>ejabberdctl modules_update_specs
    ok

    C:\Program Files\ejabberd-16.06\bin>ejabberdctl module_install mod_rest
    Problem 'error {case_clause,volumerelative}' occurred executing the command.
    Stacktrace: [{ejabberd_config,get_absolute_path,1,
                                  [{file,"src/ejabberd_config.erl"},{line,319}]},
                 {ejabberd_config,get_plain_terms_file,2,
                                  [{file,"src/ejabberd_config.erl"},{line,229}]},
                 {ejabberd_config,include_config_file,2,
                                  [{file,"src/ejabberd_config.erl"},{line,516}]},
                 {lists,flatmap,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1249}]},
                 {ejabberd_config,include_config_files,1,
                                  [{file,"src/ejabberd_config.erl"},{line,496}]},
                 {ejabberd_config,read_file,2,
                                  [{file,"src/ejabberd_config.erl"},{line,150}]},
                 {ejabberd_config,load_file,1,
                                  [{file,"src/ejabberd_config.erl"},{line,168}]},
                 {ext_mod,install,1,[{file,"src/ext_mod.erl"},{line,172}]}]

    C:\Program Files\ejabberd-16.06\bin>ejabberdctl modules_available
    atom_pubsub     Provides access to all PEP nodes via an AtomPub interface
    ejabberd_auth_http      Authentication via HTTP request
    ejabberd_mod_mam        Message Archive Management (XEP-0313)
    ejabberd_trace  Easy tracing of connections made to ejabberd
    ircd    IRC server frontend to ejabberd
    mod_archive     Supports almost all the XEP-0136 version 0.6 except otr
    mod_cron        Execute scheduled commands
    mod_grafite     Publishes Statistics via statsd/grafite
    mod_http_offline        POST offline messages to a web
    mod_log_chat    Logging chat messages in text files
    mod_logsession  Log session connections to file
    mod_logxml      Log XMPP packets to XML file
    mod_message_log Log one line per message transmission in text file
    mod_muc_log_http        Serve MUC logs on the web
    mod_openid      Transform the Jabber Server in an openid provider
    mod_post_log    Logs messages to an HTTP API
    mod_pottymouth  Filter bad words in messages
    mod_profile     User Profile (XEP-0154) in Mnesia table
    mod_rest        HTTP interface to POST stanzas into ejabberd
    mod_restful     RESTful API for ejabberd
    mod_s2s_log     Log all s2s connections in a file
    mod_shcommands  Execute shell commands
    mod_statsdx     Calculates and gathers statistics actively
    mod_webpresence Publish user presence information in the web
```

When I tried to install the module it throws error. I am not able to trace what went wrong. 
After installation, the server was continuously crashing, so I have to remove the installed module files and restart it.

Comment: provide detail crash log.

Comment: ejabberd now include mod_http_api that handle ReST calls. It is more current and is probably the one you should use.